# Why hasChildDocuments() method returns null in solr?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have a requirement that I need to deal with parent and child documents, so I have gone through the SolrJ API and some blogs and I have written the below code.

As per my program I have a parent document (i.e doc) and one child document( i.e doc2) to that. Its getting indexed and working fine.

But in next step I am trying to query on the same with some query string(i.e p_5803) which matches with the parent document. Now it has returned both the child and parent document. Till now it is fine. But why `document.hasChildDocuments()` returns "false" even for parent document?

As it has a child document it should return "true". May I know what's wrong with my program. Please check the program and output and help me out.

Note: I am using solr-solrj-4.10.3-cdh5.8.0.jar

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;

public class SolrCloudDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException,
            IOException {
        HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(
                "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1");
        System.out.println(solr.ping());

        SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument(); // main doc
        SolrInputDocument doc2 = new SolrInputDocument(); // child doc

        doc.addField("id", "p_5804");
        doc.addField("name", "Prasad chowdary");

        doc2.addField("id", "c_5804");
        doc2.addField("name", "Prasad chowdary");
        // adding a child document
        doc.addChildDocument(doc2);
        solr.add(doc);
        solr.commit();

        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("p_5803");

        QueryResponse resp = solr.query(query);

        SolrDocumentList docList = resp.getResults();
        System.out.println("docList ==> "+docList);

        for (SolrDocument document : docList) {
            System.out.println("doc ==> " + document);
            System.out.println("has child ==> " + document.hasChildDocuments());
        }
    }
}
```

### Following is the output

```
 docList ==> {numFound=2,start=0,docs=[SolrDocument{id=p_5803, name=Prasad chowdary, _version_=1568168978219532288}, SolrDocument{id=c_5803, name=Prasad chowdary}]}
doc ==> SolrDocument{id=p_5803, name=Prasad chowdary, _version_=1568168978219532288}
has child ==> false
doc ==> SolrDocument{id=c_5803, name=Prasad chowdary}
has child ==> false
```

Comment: are you sure that exact code is the one you are running? the p_5803 id does not match the data above...

Comment: @Persimmonium , yes that's the complete program what I am running and also given the output below

Comment: @prasad just curious, which version of Solr are you using? Is it the same versione of your Solrj library?

Comment: @freedev,Yeah same version I am using .

Answer (score 0):

ok, so what is happening is:

1. Solr stores both docs as *independent* docs, and then does some tricks to link between both of them, and know one is a child of the other. But you can always retrieve the children on its own.
2. you are using some analyzer that is matching both docs (probably some Ngram or fuzzy stuff on the id?), so both docs are returned. But solr does not know one is the child of the other.
3. You want parent docs to be returned only, for this you typically add a fq with a field you use to discriminate among parent/child doc:

   ```
   &fq=isparent:true
   ```
4. If you want to retrieve the children as part of the parent docs, you use 
   [ChildDocTransformerFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+Result+Documents#TransformingResultDocuments-[child]-ChildDocTransformerFactory) like this:

   ```
    &fl=*,[child parentFilter="isparent:true" limit=10]
   ```